# Game scene sometimes starts dark

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-development, tint, skybox

In my game, I tried Skybox Tint animation from dark to light. I used this on Menu and Game Over scenes. They are working but sometimes Game scene is starting dark. I tried change Skybox tint on Start function but didn't work. Only sometimes i have this problem. I couldn't find what i am changing.

Menu Scene Codes:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Menu : MonoBehaviour
{
    byte rgb;

    void Start()
    {
        rgb = 0;
        StartCoroutine(SkyboxAnimation());    
    }

    IEnumerator SkyboxAnimation()
   {
        while (rgb < 125)
        {
            RenderSettings.skybox.SetColor("_Tint", new Color32(rgb, rgb, rgb, 255));
            rgb += 3;
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.05f);
        }
    }
}
```

Everytime Menu codes are working. Scene is starting from dark to light.

Game Scene Codes on Main Camera:

```
    void Start()
    {
        RenderSettings.skybox.SetColor("_Tint", new Color32(126, 126, 126, 255));
    }
```

Game Over Scene Codes:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class GameOver : MonoBehaviour
{
    byte rgb;

    void Start()
    {
        Time.timeScale = 1;
        rgb = 0;
        StartCoroutine(SkyboxAnimation());      
    }

    IEnumerator SkyboxAnimation()
    {
        while (rgb < 125)
        {
            RenderSettings.skybox.SetColor("_Tint", new Color32(rgb, rgb, rgb, 255));
            rgb += 3;
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.05f);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to put it in `void Awake()`? You could just be setting it back light slightly after the scene is loaded. That could explain why you're seeing it (if it's going back to light quickly.)